# Mac Terminal Continuously Running a Command?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I'm trying to run the following command continuously:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of every application process to false'
```

Is there some sort of command with the following methodology?

```
repeat "enter command here"
```

If not, how could I do this?

Answer (score 3):

With a simple `while` loop, `sleep`ing in between:

```
while true; do osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of every application process to false'; sleep 1; done
```

If you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), install `watch` (`brew install watch`), and then call:

```
watch -n1 osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of every application process to false'
```

… to run it every second.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep forking new osascript processes, you can use AppleScript's repeat statement:

`osascript -e repeat -e 'tell app "System Events" to set visible of processes to false' -e 'delay 5' -e 'end repeat'`